# Dart: can't handle exceptions using the try catch block

Tags: dart, exception, try-catch, filenotfoundexception

I'm learning dart. I can't figure it out why the following dart code can't handle an  exception. What wrong am I doing below?:

```
void main() {
  print(1);
  try {
    File file = File('random_path.txt');
    print(2);
    var contents = file.readAsString();
    print(3);
    contents.then((value) => print(value));
    print(4);
  } on FileSystemException catch (e) {
    print(5);
    print(e);
  } catch (e) {
    print(6);
    print(e);
  } finally {
    print(7);
  }

  print(8);
}
```

The file `random_path.txt` doesn't exist. I was expecting the `on FileSystemException catch(e)` to catch and print `e`. But that's not a case. Here is the output:

```
1
2
3
4
7
8
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'random_path.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the error that is reported by the `contents` future, and forwarded to the future returned by `then`.

That means either adding an error handler yourself:

```dart
  contents.then(print).catchError((e, s) {
    print("Future error: $e\n$s");
  }); // Catches errors from `contents` or thrown by `print`.

// or

  contents.then(print, onError: (e, s) {
    print("Future error: $e\n$s");
  }); // Won't catch error thrown by `print`.
```

Or using an `async` function to handle the future using `await`,
which is the recommended approach:

```dart
void main() async { // <- marked as async so you can use `await`.
  print(1);
  try {
    File file = File('random_path.txt');
    print(2);
    Future<String> contents = file.readAsString();
    print(3);
    var value = await contents; // <- await gets value, or rethrows error
    print(value);
    print(4);
  } on FileSystemException catch (e) {
    print(5);
    print(e);
  } catch (e) {
    print(6);
    print(e);
  } finally {
    print(7);
  }
  print(8);
}
```

In general, always use `async` functions and `await` to deal with futures.
Using the `.then` API is mainly for low-level code which integrates different
asynchronous computations, and has to wait for more than one thing at a time.
It's what's being used internally to build a good `Future` based API that you can just `await` on. And you should just `await` when you can.

Comment: @Irn Understood, thanks. One more thing: when we use `.then` API, try-catch block is not required. Am I right on that?

Comment: The point of `await` is that it takes the result of a future, a value or error, and turns it into a "real" value or throw error, into *control flow*, so that the error can be caught by a `try`/`catch`. Without that, the error stays as a data value inside the future, and can't be caught by a `try`/`catch`, so the `try`/`catch` is neither required, nor useful. (If you forget to handle such a future error, by using a `catchError(...)` or `then(.., onError:...)` handler, the error will eventually be reported to the runtime system as an uncaught error, without ever reaching any `try`/`catch`.)